# Why req.body only get the name attribute from a POST request on node js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

this is my first question, so I'm sorry if it's a silly one.

I'm starting learn web development with javascript and node and my app project needs to send data from the ejs page and store on the database. I'm using req.body but I don't understand how this method works.

```html
<form action="/exames" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck[1]" name="exames[Hematologia]">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck[1]">Hematologia</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck[2]" name="exames[VHS]">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck[2]">VHS</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck[3]" name="exames[Coagulograma]">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck[3]">Coagulograma</label>
            </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

And in my back-end has the code :

```
var app = require("express")()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post("/", function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

And in the console shows a object `{exames: {Hematologia, VHS, Coagulograma}}` when all three checkbox are checked.

How can I pass more data beyond the attribute name?

Comment: Try to explain what you are hoping to pass. Maybe an example of what you want to receive. And if you can, try to explain under which conditions you want to receive this data.

Answer (score 0):

`req.body` stores the POST request parameters as sent by the client. 
Here is [link to the API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body).

```
req.body.exames.hematologia
// => Hematologia
req.body.exames.vhs
// => VHS
```

To pass more data, you will have to add more elements to your form. And provide us more information about what data you intend to POST.